# Mongodb and expressjs post method not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I started working on a MERN App today and im having trouble using the post method to store data in my mongodb database. I have connected to the database successfully.

I am connecting to the database as follows:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const routes = require("./controllers/postMessageController");

mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/postManagerDB",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    (err) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("MongoDB connection succeeded");
        } else {
            console.log(
                "Error while connecting to MongoDB: " +
                    JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)
            );
        }
    }
);
```

As mentioned before, the connection is all successfull. Now when i try to post a message to my database i have postman run continuosly until i cancel the request getting the following error:

```
Error while creating new record : {
  "driver": true,
  "name": "MongoError",
  "index": 0,
  "code": 13297
}
```

The following is my message model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var PostMessage = mongoose.model("PostMessage", {
    title: { type: String },
    message: { type: String },
});

module.exports = { PostMessage };
```

I also worked on my routes ./controllers/postMessageController

```
const express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var ObjectID = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;

var { PostMessage } = require("../models/postMessage");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    PostMessage.find((err, docs) => {
        if (!err) res.send(docs);
        else
            console.log(
                "Error while retrieving all records : " +
                    JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)
            );
    });
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    var newRecord = new PostMessage({
        title: req.body.title,
        message: req.body.message,
    });

    newRecord.save((err, docs) => {
        if (!err) res.send(docs);
        else
            console.log(
                "Error while creating new record : " +
                    JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)
            );
    });
});
```

In index.js i call the following:

```
require("./db");

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var postMessageRoutes = require("./controllers/postMessageController");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("Server started at: 4000");
});

app.use("/postMessages", postMessageRoutes);
```

I am very confused, the GET method works fine but the POST method is giving me issues. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Now when i try to post a message to my database i have postman run
> continuosly until i cancel the request getting the following erro

The reason is you're not sending any response to the client so the connection simply times out instead of sending any data.

Look at this code:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    var newRecord = new PostMessage({
        title: req.body.title,
        message: req.body.message,
    });

    newRecord.save((err, docs) => {
        if (!err) res.send(docs);
        else
            console.log(
                "Error while creating new record : " +
                    JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)
            );
    });
});
```

You see you're only `console.log` printing the response, not sending anything after the `else` statement if there is error to the client. You are getting error, but you need to send that error to the client if you don't want it to run out.

Example:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    var newRecord = new PostMessage({
        title: req.body.title,
        message: req.body.message,
    });

    newRecord.save((err, docs) => {
        if (!err) res.send(docs);
        else
            res.send(err)
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just added a response to send back to the client as you mentioned.